# How to retrieve active business process flow on entity in workflow C#?

Tags: c#, microsoft-dynamics, powerapps

I have a workflow which should finalize/complete business process flow which is associated with the lead entity, how can i retrieve the active business process flow which and gets its ID ? In the inputs i am sending entityName (lead) and entityid (some id of lead entity), any help appreciated

```
namespace BPF.Workflows
{
    public class Finalize : CodeActivity
    {
        [RequiredArgument]
        [Input("EntityName")]
        public InArgument<string> EntityName { get; set; }
        [RequiredArgument]
        [Input("EntityId")]
        public InArgument<string> EntityId { get; set; }

        protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext executionContext)

        {
            IWorkflowContext context = executionContext.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();
            IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = executionContext.GetExtension<IOrganizationServiceFactory>();
            IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);


            try
            {
                string leadId = EntityId.Get<string>(executionContext);
                string leadName = EntityName.Get<string>(executionContext);
                EntityReference leadRef = new EntityReference(EntityName.Get<string>(executionContext), new Guid(leadId));

                SetOrderStatusToFulfilled(leadId, service);
                FinalizeActiveBPF(leadId, service);


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Exception.Execute():", ex);
            }

        }

        private void FinalizeActiveBPF(string leadId, IOrganizationService service)
        {
            try
            {
                      //here should be the code
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception("Exception.FinalizeActiveBPF():", e);
            }
        }



        private void SetOrderStatusToFulfilled(string salesOrderId, IOrganizationService service)
        {
            try
            {
                Entity salesOrder = new Entity("lead");
                salesOrder.Id = new Guid(salesOrderId);
                salesOrder["statecode"] = new OptionSetValue(3);
                salesOrder["statuscode"] = new OptionSetValue(100001);

                service.Update(salesOrder);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception("Exception.SetOrderStatusToFulfilled():", e);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

i tried this but this doesnt work :

```
Entity activeBPF = UserWs.Retrieve(leadName, new Guid(leadId), new ColumnSet("processid"));

Guid activebpfProcessId = activeBPF.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("processid");
```